# OMXPlayer freezes when playing video

Tags: raspbian, omxplayer

I am using OMXPlayer to play some HD videos on my RaspberryPi 3 with latest Raspbian Jessie image. It run perfectly for some time (sometimes 20 minutes, sometimes 3 hours, sometimes 5 hours) but then it freezes. CPU and RAM values are normal. I am running OMXPlayer with this command:

```
/usr/bin/omxplayer --no-osd --loop myVideo.mp4
```

and after OMXPlayer freezes I get this message in console:

```
omxplayer.bin: OMXCore.cpp:785 OMX_ERRORTYPE COMXCoreCOmponent:FreeInputBuffers(): Assertion 'm_omx_input_buffers.size() == m_omx_input_available.size()' failed.
```

Googled and only advice that I found to solve this problem is to set GPU memory to 128 instead to default 64, I did it, but nothing changed.

Anybody here had similar experience with OMXPlayer ? Is there any way to fix this ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was because old raspberry pi firmware and old omxplayer version, so I recommend you to update firmware by:

```
sudo rpi-update
```

and to install and download OMXPlayer version 6c90c75 from this link to avoid freezing problems:

http://omxplayer.sconde.net/

Comment: I just updated the RPi 3 firmware and made sure I was using the latest omxplayer build (dfea8c9), unfortunately, it is still freezing. Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Based on [this thread](https://github.com/popcornmix/omxplayer/issues/187), I discovered that installing an old version of Omxplayer (from Mar 9, 2014) solved my freezing issue.  You can download old versions of Omxplayer [here](http://omxplayer.sconde.net/) and install the downloaded .deb file using:

```
 sudo dpkg -i /path/to/your_install_file.deb
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar problem here... in my case, I was pushing a video from a nodeJS server on the local network.  If I changed the video at the server, OMXPlayer would just crash.

I removed the OMXPlayer `--loop` flag.  Instead, perform a while loop in a bash script.  This solution fixed it for me...

```
#!/bin/bash
sleep .5
while [1]
do
    omxplayer -b -r -live http://192.168.1.16:3000/fileserver/channelA
done
```